# Differenziate between int and Integer parameter when using reflection to call a method

Tags: java, reflection

```
public void getData(int i){
    System.out.println("1");
}
public void getData(Integer i){
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

The following line of code

```
this.getClass().getMethod("getData",Integer.class).invoke(this, 10);
```

prints 2 , how to make it print 1?

Comment: The title is misleading. IMHO something like "Distinguish `int` and `Integer` parameters when invoking method via reflection" would be accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are requesting the method that accepts an `Integer`. Change that to the one that takes an `int` and you are done:

```
this.getClass().getMethod("getData",int.class).invoke(this, 10);
```

Note that there as `int.class` although `int` is a primitive type. It exists exactly for this reason.

Comment: The same value is also available as the public static final constant TYPE in the Integer class.

Comment: @lpratlong Thanks for the ideone example.